# Does maven-compiler-plugin consider dependencies when checking for stale sources?

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, maven-compiler-plugin

Ant's [depend](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/depend.html) task allows one to recompile Java source-code if any of its dependencies (referenced classes, not module dependencies) have been modified. I took a quick look at [org.apache.maven.plugin.CompilerMojo](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/maven/plugins/tags/maven-compiler-plugin-2.3.2/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugin/CompilerMojo.java?revision=992608&view=co) and [org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.util.scan.StaleSourceScanner](https://fisheye.codehaus.org/browse/~raw,r=8676/plexus/plexus-components/tags/plexus-compiler-1.8/plexus-compiler-api/src/main/java/org/codehaus/plexus/compiler/util/scan/StaleSourceScanner.java) and by the looks of it, they don't take dependencies into account at all. It looks as if source-code gets recompiled if its timestamp is newer than that of the class file (plus some delta).

Did I miss anything or is Maven disregarding the case where the source-code didn't change but its dependency did (hence they both need to be recompiled)?

Answer (score 0):

You did not miss anything. Maven is disregarding that case. You'll have to work around it with a clean build.

The [maven-versions-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/) can check whether newer versions are available, so there's half the equation. The clean rebuild is still manual work.

Comment: I believe you misunderstood my question. I was talking about referenced classes, not module dependencies. maven-versions-plugin only deals with module dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I use the maven-antrun-plugin. There you can configure it. I don't think it is automatic though. What I mean in you have to specify is manually first time you compile it. After wards maven handles your problem.